# $ B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda}=\bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ \ \{A_\lambda \} , \ \lambda \in I $ be any family of sets , then show that

$$ B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda}=\bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda) $$

**Answer:**

If the index set $ \ \lambda \ $ be a countable set then I can prove the result using Induction principle .

But if the index set $ \ I $ be uncountable , then how to prove it ?

Help me proving this.

Comment: What is your definition of generalised union for (possibly) uncountable collections?

Comment: Why exactly did you withdrew your acceptance? You are free to do so of course, and nothing is wrong with the answer that is accepted now, but I do like to know your reasons. I am here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a definition for generalised union, such as this:$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in I} A_\lambda= \{x\mid \exists \lambda\in I~(x\in A_\lambda)\}$$

Use this definion, and that of ordinary union, disjunction, and existential quantification, to show that the general elements of each set $B\cup \bigcup_{\lambda\in I} A_\lambda$ and $\bigcup_{\lambda\in I} (B\cup A_\lambda)$ are elements of the other.

Answer (score -1):

We can show equality by two-way subsets as there's no need to be confused by the possibly uncountable union. We must only know the principles of subsets and union:

Let $x \in B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda}$; then either:

1. $ x \in B$ which implies $x \in B \cup A_\lambda \subset \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda)$
2. $ x \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} A_\lambda$ which implies $x \in A_{\lambda_0}$ so $x \in B \cup A_{\lambda_0} \subset \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda)$

In any case $B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda} \subset \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda)$.

For the other direction;

Let $x \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda)$; then we have $x \in (B \cup A_{\lambda_0})$ for some index. Then either:

1. $x \in B$
2. $ x\in A_{\lambda_0}$

In any case $x \in B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda}$

so $B \cup \bigcup_{ \lambda \in I}A_{\lambda}=\bigcup_{\lambda \in I} (B \cup A_\lambda)$

Remark; when I write $A_{\lambda_0}$ I mean there's an index such that $x \in A_{\lambda_0}$

Comment: Why down vote, may I ask?

Comment: I did not downvote

Comment: I could ask: If this is downvoted then why is my answer not downvoted? (+1) It is essentially the same.

Comment: @drhab, actually Mariah might  have downvoted my question also as  his/her answer was downvoted.

Comment: @MONJURALAM I didn't :) I find your question quite legitimate which is why I answered it.

Comment: @MONJURALAM You should leave that decision fully to Mariah. Legitimate on its own is for some a reason to upvote, for others it is not.

Comment: @drhab, I thank you for your nice answer. But ................

Comment: @yourmath but..... what?

Comment: @yourmath What exactly are you trying to say? Please make that clear.

Comment: @drhab, you should understand what I said.

Comment: @yourmath I do *not* understand that, hence ask for explanation. If you do not give any then you behave irresponsible (unwilling to respond). If this situation remains then you encourage me to think of you as someone who deserves no further attention.

Answer (score -1):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in B\cup(\bigcup_{\lambda\in I}A_{\lambda})$
- $x\in B\text{ or }x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in I}A_{\lambda}$
- $x\in B\text{ or some }\lambda\in I\text{ exists such that }x\in A_{\lambda}$
- $\text{ some }\lambda\in I\text{ exists such that }x\in B\text{ or }x\in A_{\lambda}$
- $\text{ some }\lambda\in I\text{ exists such that }x\in B\cup A_{\lambda}$
- $x\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in I}(B\cup A_{\lambda})$

The first and last bullet together allow the conclusion that: $$B\cup(\bigcup_{\lambda\in I}A_{\lambda})=\bigcup_{\lambda\in I}(B\cup A_{\lambda})$$on base of the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) (i.e. sets are completely determined by their elements).

Comment: lol it seems we have a network against us

Comment: @Mariah It surely looks like that. I cannot find another explanation. It is good thing to laugh about it in the sense that you do not allow it to harm you. Nevertheless it is also very sad that things like this happen here.

Comment: it seems to me that MONJUR ALAM and yourmath are one and the same; this explains our two immediate downvotes, your answer being removed as 'accepted', and the comment as yourmath in my answer. In fact, I compared their questions, and the style of writing is very very similar in both accounts.

Comment: @Mariah That is also my impression. I flagged my own answer in order to attend moderators.